# cannot access class proj.new.exampleclass (in module Proj) because module Proj does not export proj.new to module javafx.fxml

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

Project file structure:

```
Proj 
|__
   src
   |___proj
       |
       |___Main.java
       |
       |____main.fxml 
       |
       |___new (subpackage)
           | 
           |___exampleclass.java (controller class)
```

main.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="250.0" prefWidth="250.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/17" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="proj.new.exampleclass">
```

exampleclass.java

```
package proj.new;

public class exampleclass implements Initializable {
...
}

...
```

Exception:

```
cannot access class  proj.new.exampleclass (in module Proj) because module Proj does not export proj.new to module javafx.fxml
```

the package `new` is in the build path of Proj, and `new` is checked under `order and export` in Proj. I made the `new` subpackage by creating a folder and adding the exampleclass java file into it, (on eclipse)

Comment: `new` is kind of a special keyword in Java.  I don’t recommend calling a package or anything else `new`, so change that.  Also, search for Java naming conventions, study them and apply them to any code you post online.  Next, [understand Java modules](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html) and apply what you have learned. Then study the [openjfx guide for Eclipse](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#modular) especially “2. Edit the module-info class”.  Fix the module-info.java to open the package with your controller to javafx.fxml.

Comment: Oops cross posted some info in comments, sorry for duplication.

Comment: You might also consider not to use [JPMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System) by deleting your `module-info.java` file.